# Ruby-like Syntax Highlighting in VIM for Thor

Tags: ruby, vim, syntax-highlighting, thor, vim-syntax-highlighting

How can I configure vim to use the same syntax highlighting for [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor) as it does for ruby? When I'm editing a *.thor file, I can use `:set syntax=ruby`, which works, but is not permanent. Is there a way to do something in my .vimrc file to conditionally set the syntax to ruby if it's *.thor? Maybe create a thor syntax file and inherit from ruby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.thor set filetype=ruby
```

I think should suffice... maybe this if you want to customize it later:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.thor set filetype=thor
au! Syntax thor source $HOME/.vim/syntax/thor.vim
```

and copy ruby .vim syntax highlight file to `$HOME/.vim/syntax/thor.vim`

Comment: Thanks, the first part was all I needed. This way is actually better than just setting the syntax because it takes care of indenting too.

Answer (score 4):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.thor set syntax=ruby
```

should work.